# PHPExcel return blank on getCalculatedValue

Tags: php, phpexcel

Good day everyone :D
Thank you all for taking a look, much obliged.

This is a PHPExcel Question.
I have in the Excel file, `A1=-1`, `B2=A2=0`, so `B2` should return "FALSE".
However, when trying to retrive it through `getCalculatedValue`, it returns blank.

```
echo $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('B2')->getCalculatedValue();
```

For those interested, the whole code is here.

```
/** Include path **/
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . '../Classes/');

/** PHPExcel_IOFactory */
include 'PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';

/** Load Excel File **/
$inputFileName = './TrueFalse.xlsx';
echo 'Loading file ',pathinfo($inputFileName,PATHINFO_BASENAME),' using IOFactory to identify the format<br />';
$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($inputFileName);

/** Change A2 Value **/
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A2','=-1');

/** Calculate and State B2 Value **/
echo '<br><br> Show Calculated Value for B2';
echo '<br> B2 = ';
echo $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('B2')->getCalculatedValue();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a PHP echo statement will display nothing for a FALSE value. Either use

```
var_dump($objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('B2')->getCalculatedValue());
```

though var_dump should normally only be used for debugging; or something like:

```
echo $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('B2')->getCalculatedValue() ? 'TRUE' : 'FALSE';
```